# export c++ class for use in new project

Tags: c++, class, visual-studio-2013

I have created a C++ project that contains some classes I would like to reuse, having spent quite a while searching and finding many ways of doing this, none of which are well explained I am still stuck.

I understand you could create a library to do this, or even export a dll?

But not too sure on the specifics of how to do so.

I just need to be able to use the classes in a new project, any help would be much appreciated

I am using Visual Studio.

Thanks

Sam

Comment: Copy the files to your new project Directory.  Then add them in the right tree control to your project. But then you have two versions of each copied file. Remember.

Comment: project>add existing item, and add the source files. I would say "don't use DLLs if you can avoid them", you'd have a project for the DLL and one for the main stuff and compile/debug/run/deploy the wrong one maaaaany times...

Comment: For Visual Studio:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235627.aspx
and
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx

But its still faster to copy your cpp files and headers if you want to reuse them. Because it takes more time to setup a static / dynamic library for your projects than copying the cpp files.

Comment: You could export your project as a template with only the files not excluded from your project to be a part therein. Another way is to create a .dll file with your code and including headers, linking etc as any other library. Or a cheaper way is to just copy the relevant files to your new project.